# VBA Excel saving as a PDF based on the sheet colours-Create array of sheets based on tab color

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I would like to eligible my PDF document to save, although within the sheets with specified color.

How can I do that?

[image]

```
  Sub SavecolorTabtoPDF()

  Dim ws As Worksheet

  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

  If Tab Color = "Blue, Accent 1, Darker 25%" Then
        'export as pdf
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="C:\" & Left(ws.Name, Len(ws.Name) - 2) & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End If
  Next ws

 End Sub
```

Comment: My code looks pretty much like this - see above.

Comment: Hi Mate, I will check it right now. I had a weekend :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop through the sheets and create an array of sheets based on tab color.

This will create your array of sheets, then pdf them as one.

```
Sub MakeArraySheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ArraySheets() As String
    Dim x As Variant

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Tab.ColorIndex = 55 Then
            ReDim Preserve ArraySheets(x)
            ArraySheets(x) = sh.Name
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next sh

    Sheets(ArraySheets).Select

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                                    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
                                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True



End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code, but still doesn't work. Could you see my last update and check what is wrong there? I am not clued up enough at this stage, so the full code would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know the way how to find the color number to be honest. DO you know it?

Comment: Unfortunately not working.
Only all sheets are activated. It still must have been something somewhere :(

Comment: Yeah Mate! It works, when I changed to the sh.Tab.ColorIndex = 55. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 dim wsheet as worksheet
  For Each wsheet In Thisworkbook.Worksheets
    if wsheet.tab.colorindex = 1 then
         Worksheet.SaveAs(*parameters*)
    end if
  next wsheet
```

EDIT: The *colorindex* for your specified color is **55**. Find out by filling a cell with that color and running "mgbox activecell.interior.colorindex"
EDIT2: Removed "interior" before colorindex

Comment: Unfortunately not working. Could you take a look above, what I tried?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know how this slipped past me (I do know, I've been dead tired for the past few days, so a big sorry from me), but try it without the "interior". Just "tab.colorindex=".